# Which verions of pygames run with python 3.2.3 on Mac OS

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pygame for Python 3 on OSX Mountain Lion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12362449/pygame-for-python-3-on-osx-mountain-lion)

The web is filled with obscure,difficult to follow references, and out of context postings  for getting pygames to run with python V3 or greater on a MAC.  Most people point out that there is an installer already for python 3.2.3 for MAC, but there is little info how well pygames (and which versions of pygames) could successfully run with anything beyond python 2.7 on a MAC.  Mixed into this problem are the
3 different MAC OS, leopard, lion, and now mountain lion.  1)So I am wondering what peoples experience are with pygames plus python 3 version or greater on all these various MAC OS.
2) Also, if somebody were up to the challange of creating better step by step instructions for a novice to homebew install pygames for all these MAC OS with python 3 (assuming it works at all).  My 13-year old son is trying to complete a very nice pygames tutorial on his Mac running mountain lion, and the tutorial is geared for python 3 and above. So now we are stuck, because the tutorial is written for python 3.  Any help or advice would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to actually install it?

Comment: Clearly somebody is asking a very similar question within the same time period, and maybe our threads or questions could be combined but I dont know how to do that. In addition to asking for step by step intallation instructions, I am also asking for general knowledge that there is a version of Pygame that will run with Python 3.x on mountain lion or any Mac. I have not tried any installalation yet, as the only auto installers are for Pygames running on python 2.7.  I am new to Mac so I would need more step by step instructions as well.