# Pygame for Python 3 on OSX Mountain Lion?

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, osx-mountain-lion

I have been trying to get this to work for days now, with no luck. All of the installation walkthroughs I can find either talk about pygame on mountain lion with python 2.x, or pygame with python 3 on osx 10.6, but never all 3 together.

Sorry if this is long, but here's what I've tried so far...

First I tried using homebrew and pip, following this: 
http://florian-berger.de/en/articles/installing-pygame-for-python-3-on-os-x

But I got the same errors mentioned here: 
[Error when Installing Pygame on Mountain Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11954497/error-when-installing-pygame-on-mountain-lion)

So, having made the modification suggested in the answer to that question, I tried to compile pygame from source, following pygame.org's directions for mountain lion: http://www.pygame.org/wiki/MacCompile
(However, those instructions require NumPy, which I couldn't get because as far as I can tell it doesn't exist for python 3)

But the furthest I could get with trying to compile it like that was:

```
In file included from src/imageext.c:51:
/Library/Frameworks/SDL_image.framework/Versions/Current/Headers/SDL_image.h:27:21: error: /Library/Frameworks/SDL.framework/Versions/Current/Headers/SDL/SDL.h: Too many levels of symbolic links
/Library/Frameworks/SDL_image.framework/Versions/Current/Headers/SDL_image.h:28:29: error: /Library/Frameworks/SDL.framework/Versions/Current/Headers/SDL/SDL_version.h: Too many levels of symbolic links
/Library/Frameworks/SDL_image.framework/Versions/Current/Headers/SDL_image.h:29:28: error: /Library/Frameworks/SDL.framework/Versions/Current/Headers/SDL/begin_code.h: Too many levels of symbolic links
/Library/Frameworks/SDL_image.framework/Versions/Current/Headers/SDL_image.h:136:28: error: /Library/Frameworks/SDL.framework/Versions/Current/Headers/SDL/close_code.h: Too many levels of symbolic links
src/imageext.c: In function ‘PyInit_imageext’:
src/imageext.c:675: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘PyCObject_Check’
src/imageext.c:675: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘PyCObject_AsVoidPtr’
error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

And newbie that I am, I don't know what to try next. (Yes, I have googled. All I could determine is that I have some kind of symlink loop(s), but what/where and how to fix it I don't exactly know.)

If there is some ridiculously easy fix to this that one of you smart people can point out to me... that would be GREAT (even if it makes me feel like an idiot!)!

Failing that, alternate strategies?? All I want is to use pygame with python 3 on mountain lion... if anyone has done this, I would LOVE to hear how!

P.S. I'm obviously new here, and just learning to code... please explain things to me as if I were a 5-year-old. Seriously. :)

Comment: Numpy definitely does exist for Python 3, although if you have to compile that manually as well, things will get more complicated. Can you get numpy from homebrew or macports and use that to compile pygame?

Comment: Hmm, so it's (lack of) numpy that's causing this after all? I will take another look at the numpy situation and see if I can get it to work (tried for a while the other day but no luck)... thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: The problem you're seeing doesn't look like it's related to numpy, but that might be the next thing you run into. I just wanted to note that numpy is working on Python 3.

Comment: OK, got numpy from macports. But unfortunately I still can't compile pygame... grrr!
Still getting lots of errors related to the SDL frameworks, and I also keep getting:
    error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit status 1

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: The bit about gcc is secondary - the compiler fails because of the SDL errors, and then the code running the compiler reports that the compiler (gcc) has failed.

Comment: Thanks Thomas... so what can I do about these SDL errors? I did this (from the pygame.org instructions for compiling on mountain lion):

6. Before compilation of pygame:

  a. SDL_x header files refer to SDL as <SDL/SDL_yy.h> However, a SDL directory is not under
the include directory of SDL (SDL/Headers). To fix this in a simple way:

    i. Went to directory
          /Library/Frameworks/SDL.framework/Headers
     then made a link as follows:
          ln -s SDL ./

...but when I go back and check that link, it seems not to go anywhere. What am I missing here?

Comment: Sorry, no ideas about that. I'm not a Mac user myself.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem. I just created an SDL folder and copied sources files into it.

So instead of:

```
ln -s SDL .
```

go:

```
mkdir SDL; cp *.h SDL
```

It's ugly, but it works.

Comment: Ok i got it: use absolute path when doing ln. ln -s /Library/Frameworks/SDL.framework/Headers /Library/Frameworks/SDL.framework/Headers/SDL. from: http://superuser.com/questions/322319/when-creating-a-symbolic-link-how-do-i-troubleshoot-too-many-levels-of-symboli